# Passing parameters from api in ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I am new to Ionic and trying to pass api from providers to application's ts page but I am getting an error, maybe I am passing the wrong id.

TS part:

```
 export class CardsPage {
    currentItems: Item[];
    id: any;
    getData: Object;
    categories;
 constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public api:Api, navParams: 
       NavParams, items: Items, public http: HttpClient) {
             this.id = navParams.get('idName') ||'';
             console.log(this.id); 
 this.api.getCategoryPosts(this.id).subscribe(data=>{
   console.log(data)
   this.getData = data
},err=>{
     console.log(err)
 })
 }
    openItem(item){
    this.navCtrl.push('ItemDetailPage', {
    itemName: item
  });
}
```

}

Api:

```
getCategoryPosts(category: any) {
      return this.http.get(`${this.api_url}/posts?categories=${category.id}`);
  }
```

I have posted the code part about my API and ts file now I want to pass data to next page using parameters. I wanted to know what should I pass in parameter to get data displayed in next page

Comment: Please post a copy of the error.

Comment: Reference error: category is not defined Reference error. Category is not defined at new CardsPage

Answer (score 0):

According to your code, You are passing id directly to the Service's `getCategoryPosts` method. Therefore use `category` instead of `category.id` as below.

```
getCategoryPosts(category: any) {
      return this.http.get(`${this.api_url}/posts?categories=${category}`);
  }
```

Comment: I still get this error:: - Reference error: category is not defined Reference error. Category is not defined at new CardsPage.